# XDebug view HTML output

Tags: xdebug

Hi I'm using XDEBUG to debug my WordPress code, is it possible to view the page building up in the browser while debugging? At the moment the page just hangs until the debugging process is finished then displays the fully rendered page. Ideally I'd like to see the page building up bit by bit as I debug through the theme's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about the Wordpress internals, but if it uses output buffering (which i guess it does) the output is sent to the client all at once. Maybe you can disable output buffering somehow. http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: Can't find anything on that, my local server's output_buffering value is off however. Maybe someone else can show me how to disable WordPress buffering.

Comment: If there is no output control you can use flush() whenever you want to sent the output to the client http://nl3.php.net/flush. I must warn you tho, using this can get you very unexpected results and/or errors.

Comment: I thought there must be a more straightforward way, thanks though.